# Vlookup/Display one-to-many relationship in excel

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a massive training catalogue for employees.
Each employee has a job Position ( Example: Accountant)
A Lawyer has to take multiple courses in order to be an accountant.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to input the employee job position in one cell and make it display ALL of the courses he needs to undertake.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Vlookup only displays the first course, I don't know how I am able to do this in excel ( Would normally use a data vizualization software..)

Comment: Use auto filter, [advanced filter](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/advanced-filter.html), or a pivot table. No need for any code or formula here.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, as I mentioned, the catalogue is massive, using a pivot table would waste a lot of time and makes the workbook crash.

Comment: Well, I suggested 2 other solutions too. Any other solution in VBA would either use filters too or would have to loop through your data and produce a heavy load too. So I suggest to use the advanced filter.

Comment: If your data is so massive that it causes crashes then you used the wrong tool. Excel is no database. Use a real database like SQL or at least some database tool like MS Access then. So you can connect to them from Excel and run a SQL query for example. That should be performant.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, I agree with you, But unfortunately the people that I'm supposed to create this dashboard for, don't know how to use MS Access

Comment: Well, still try advanced filter then. • If this does not work too then you will have to take a decision. Example: 50 People fit into a bus. You tried to get them into your car. They don't fit. You decide to take the bus or a train. • The decision for your question is pretty much the same ;)

Comment: Do all these courses have to be in seperate cells? It will take a lot of processing time, cause if you don't want to use filters as @Pᴇʜ suggests you'll need heavy array formulas. If it can be done in one cell, (even then calculations would probably be heavy) it should help on calculation time.